# Unable to execute PHP from gedit using 'external tools' feature

Tags: ubuntu, development-environment, gedit, ubuntu-12.10

In my gedit, I set an external tool like this:-

Name: `Run PHP`

Edit:-

```
#!/bin/sh
php
```

Save: `Nothing`

Input: `Current document`

Output: `Display in bottom pane`

Applicability: `All documents`

But it is not outputting anything in the bottom pane. It just shows this:-

```
Running tool: Run PHP
Done.
```

It doesnt show the actual output, but if there is any syntax or runtime error in the code, the error will be shown in red color in the bottom pane. The problem is only with the actual output of the script.

Can anyone help? I have attached the screenshot of my gedit settings window below.

(I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 btw). Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that output doesn't have new line ... append echo "" or something after PHP command (or echo PHP_EOL to PHP code)

```
#!/bin/sh
php
echo ""
```